# How to inspect parsed Aeson Value?

Tags: haskell, aeson

How can I browse large `Aeson` `Values`? I know there should be a string I'm interested in nested somewhere in the structure. How can I find it?

So far I only know how to query constructor and found out it's an Array. How can I dig deeper than that?

```
> take 20 $ show bt
"Array (fromList [Obj"
```

Comment: Maybe something like this `"find_this" `isInfixOf`  $ show bt"` ?

Comment: Do you know the structure of the data before you are parsing it?

Comment: @JustinWood No, It's a large object that I know nothing about. Some elements have content I expect and I'm interested in their neighborhood only. I can `grep` them, but I'm hoping that GHCI is better tool to find its path than text editor after pretty printing the content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `lens` package has useful functions for inspecting tree-like structures like JSON `Value`s. There's also the `lens-aeson` package with extra JSON-specific functions.

```
import Data.Text
import Data.Aeson
import Data.Aeson.Lens (_Value,_String) -- this is from lens-aeson
import Data.Foldable (toList)

import Control.Lens (Fold,folding,universeOf,toListOf,paraOf,preview)
```

We can begin by defining a lens [`Fold`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.7/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#t:Fold) that extracts the immediate child `Values` of a given JSON `Value`:

```
vchildren :: Fold Value Value
vchildren = folding $ \v -> case v of
    Object o -> toList o
    Array a -> toList a
    _ -> []
```

[`folding`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.7/docs/Control-Lens-Fold.html#v:folding) is a function from `lens` that creates a `Fold` out a function that returns a list. A list of `Value`s, in our case.

We can combine `vchildren` with the [`universeOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.7/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#v:universeOf) function from [`Control.Lens.Plated`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.7/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html) to get a function that extracts *all* the transitive descendants of a `Value`, including itself:

```
allValues :: Value -> [Value]
allValues = universeOf vchildren
```

And this function extracts all the texts contained in a `Value`. It uses the [`_String`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-aeson-1.0.0.3/docs/Data-Aeson-Lens.html#v:_String) prism from [`Data.Aeson.Lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-aeson-1.0.0.3/docs/Data-Aeson-Lens.html) (a [`Prism`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.6/docs/Control-Lens-Prism.html) is a bit like a "reified" pattern that can be passed around):

```
allTexts :: Value -> [Text]
allTexts = toListOf (folding allValues . _String)
```

`Control.Lens.Plated` also has interesting functions like [`paraOf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.7/docs/Control-Lens-Plated.html#v:paraOf), that let you build "paramorphims". A paramorphism is a "controlled destruction" of a tree-like structure starting from the leaves, and building the results upward. For example, this function

```
vpara :: (Value -> [r] -> r) -> Value -> r
vpara = paraOf vchildren
```

takes as its first parameter another function that receives the "current node" along with the intermediate results for the nodes below, and builds the intermediate result for the current node.

`vpara` will start consuming the JSON value from the leaves (the intermediate result list for those nodes is simply `[]`) and proceeds upwards.

One possible use of `vpara` is obtaining the list of paths in the JSON that end in a text that matches some condition, like this:

```
type Path = [Value]

pathsThatEndInText :: (Text -> Bool) -> Value -> [Path]
pathsThatEndInText pred = vpara func
  where
    func :: Value -> [[Path]] -> [Path]
    func v@(String txt) _ | pred txt = [[v]]
    func v l@(_:_) = Prelude.map (v:) (Prelude.concat l)
    func _ _ = []
```

To obtain a somewhat readable description of one of the paths returned by `pathsThatEndInText`:

```
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HM
import qualified Data.Vector as V

describePath :: Path -> [String]
describePath (v:vs) = Prelude.zipWith step (v:vs) vs
  where
    step (Object o) next = (unpack . Prelude.head . HM.keys . HM.filter (==next)) o
    step (Array a) next = (show . maybe (error "not found") id) (V.elemIndex next a)
    step _ _ = error "should not happen"
```

Finally, here's an example JSON value for testing the above functions in ghci:

```
exampleJSON :: Value
exampleJSON = maybe Null id (preview _Value str)
  where
    str = "[{ \"k1\" : \"aaa\" },{ \"k2\" : \"ccc\" }, { \"k3\" : \"ddd\" }]"
```

And here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/danidiaz/3a80eac809a56ae3df59).